# R: Train data and test data have the same prediction

Tags: r, lm, predict

I am trying to use the lm and predict function to test if the prediction is correct enough. It turns out that the train data and the test data have the same prediction.

```
set.seed(1);
x = matrix(rnorm(300*100),300,100)
y = rnorm(300);
test.x = matrix(rnorm(300*100),300,100)
test.y = rnorm(300);

xy = data.frame(y, x)
fit = lm(y~x, xy)

x.df = data.frame(x)
pred1 = predict(fit, newdata=x.df)

test.x.df = data.frame(test.x)
pred = predict(fit, newdata=test.x.df)

sum(abs(pred1-pred))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `lm()` you are using the formula `y ~ x`. Although you have a column `y` in your data, there is no column `x`. So although `lm()` is using all of your `x` columns, it gets the names wrong

```
names(fit$model)
[1] "y" "x"
```

Whenever you call `predict()` on using that model, it will return the fitted values of the model, since it can't match the columns.

Change it to:

```
fit = lm(y ~ ., xy)
```

And you will see that now it looks differently:

```
names(fit$model)
[1] "y"    "X1"   "X2"   "X3"   "X4"   "X5"   "X6"   "X7"   "X8"   "X9"   "X10" 
... 
[100] "X99"  "X100"
```

At the end, it will use the data you passed in the `newdata` argument:

```
sum(abs(pred1-pred))
[1] 196.9676
```